# Convert DOCX to PDF with documents4j (Which Internally uses VBScript for the conversion)

Tags: java, pdf, docx, documents4j

The following is the simple code snippet which I am trying to use to convert a DOCX file into a PDF on my local system, which is as it is picked up from http://documents4j.com/#/.

1. Running this piece of code as a part of service inside a web app (.war) deployed on **Tomcat 9.0.37** which is running as Windows service.
2. Created the below folder C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop (**Running documents4j application as Windows service**).
3. MS Office professional 2016 is installed (**licenced copy**).

Well with same configuration on **VM 1: Windows server 2012** and **VM 2: Windows server 2019** as mentioned in above three points. I'm able to convert the DOCX to PDF in my **VM 1 : Windows server 2012**. But the below problem I'm facing in **VM 2: Windows server 2019**.

On calling execute method the current thread is getting blocked for forever, which leads to memory leak. Please find the below error on execute method.

```
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [appName] is still processing a request that has yet to finish. This is very likely to create a memory leak. You can control the time allowed for requests to finish by using the unloadDelay attribute of the standard Context implementation. Stack trace of request processing thread:[
 java.base@11.0.5/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:194)
 java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:885)
 java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1039)
 java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1345)
 java.base@11.0.5/java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:232)
 com.documents4j.job.AbstractFutureWrappingPriorityFuture.get(AbstractFutureWrappingPriorityFuture.java:204)
 com.documents4j.job.AbstractFutureWrappingPriorityFuture.get(AbstractFutureWrappingPriorityFuture.java:10)
 com.documents4j.job.ConversionJobAdapter.execute(ConversionJobAdapter.java:13)
```

**Code Snippet 1**:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import com.documents4j.api.DocumentType;
import com.documents4j.api.IConverter;
import com.documents4j.job.LocalConverter;

public class WordMLToPDF2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File inputWord  = new File("C:\\Users\\anshu\\Downloads\\test.docx")
        , outputFile  = new File("C:\\Users\\anshu\\Downloads\\test.pdf");
        try  {
            InputStream docxInputStream = new FileInputStream(inputWord);
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            IConverter converter = LocalConverter.builder()
                       .baseFolder(tmpDir)
                       .workerPool(20, 25, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                       .processTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                       .build();
            converter.convert(docxInputStream).as(DocumentType.DOCX).to(outputStream).as(DocumentType.PDF).execute();
            outputStream.close();
            System.out.println("success");
            converter.shutDown();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Below dependencies which I've configured in pom.xml

```
   <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>docx4j-documents4j-local</artifactId>
            <version>8.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>docx4j-JAXB-ReferenceImpl</artifactId>
            <version>8.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- API, java.xml.bind module -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Runtime, com.sun.xml.bind module -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**EDIT:**

After analyzing the source code. What I understood is:

- Internally documents4j executes a VBScript with the help of another library zt-exec (ZeroTurnaround Process Executor) to start the WINWORD or for the conversion of DOCX to PDF or to stop the WINWORD
- WINWORD program freezes When it executes **wordApplication.Documents.Open(inputFile, False, True, False)** [word_convert](https://github.com/documents4j/documents4j/blob/master/documents4j-transformer-msoffice/documents4j-transformer-msoffice-word/src/main/resources/word_convert.vbs#L37)
- In above statement wordApplication holds the object of Word.Application

  [word_start](https://github.com/documents4j/documents4j/blob/master/documents4j-transformer-msoffice/documents4j-transformer-msoffice-word/src/main/resources/word_start.vbs)
  [word_convert](https://github.com/documents4j/documents4j/blob/master/documents4j-transformer-msoffice/documents4j-transformer-msoffice-word/src/main/resources/word_convert.vbs)
  [word_shutdwon](https://github.com/documents4j/documents4j/blob/master/documents4j-transformer-msoffice/documents4j-transformer-msoffice-word/src/main/resources/word_shutdown.vbs)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251473/discussion-on-question-by-anshu-convert-docx-to-pdf-with-documents4j-library).

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and my conclusion is that you need to create the service that runs the document conversion with the same user that runs the service if you won't do it it will run with local system(or with any other user you set to run which is different from the one who created the service) and will try to create and read folders of the user that created the service and then it will get stuck.
After I created the service with admin user and also ran the service with the same user it fixed my issue.
In addition as mentioned you should also make sure that the following folders exists and if not create them:

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop

In case you don't have permission to log in to the system with the admin user but you have it credentials you can create the service with Task scheduler and create a one time task that will run the service creation as the admin user and then set the same user to run the service